# Remove '�' from different encoded file when reading in C#

Tags: c#, .net, encoding, non-ascii-characters, file-encodings

I can't control what encoding some of our clients save a file, and when it's ASCII the file may have missing characters that then show, '�'.  How can I remove these characters, '�', after the file is read?

I am reading the file with the below line, but for each column would like to replace that character with a whitespace in C# .NET.

```
   using (var parser = new TextFieldParser("", Encoding.UTF8))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you can [create a UTF-8 `Encoding`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/89856k4b(v=vs.110).aspx) with a custom error replacement:

```
var encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding(
    "UTF-8",
    null,
    new DecoderReplacementFallback(string.Empty));

using (var parser = new TextFieldParser("", encoding)) {
    ⋮
}
```

I don’t know if the encoder fallback is allowed to be `null`. Replace it with `new EncoderReplacementFallback(string.Empty)` if not!

Comment: Worked like a charm